# Differentiate the following functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-forms

Let
$$y(x)= 4 x^3 e^{2x},$$

then

$$y'(x) = 4 \times 3 \, x^2 e^{2x} + 4 \, x^3 \times 2 e^{2x} =  12 \, x^2 e^{2x} + 8 \, x^3 e^{2x}$$

Does this look correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks good.

Comment: It looks good. Just remember that for $f$ and $g$ functions of $x$, then $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$, where the primes denote total differentiation wrt $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm just doing my homework and I've never used a forum like this before so my layout might be a bit off until I grasp the function text fully. Thanks for the edits and replies, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you result is correct.
If you're uncertain in the future you may also like to use Wolfram|Alpha, see [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+4x^3e^%282x%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/dx%204x%5E3e%5E%282x%29) for this result.
It does also provide a step-by-step solution.